# AWS S3 an easy way to clone the file in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a link to a file on S3. Theoretically I can get a bucket and all its permissions from it, but is there an easy way to clone the file in the same folder of the same bucket with the same settings? I know that there is [CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html), but it looks difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easier programmatic way I know than to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject method as described in the link you provided.